# Why Kosaraju's algorithm cannot use original graph by increasing finish time?

Tags: graphs

I saw [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19652/kosaraju-s-algorithm-why-transpose), and it explains about why kosaraju's algorithm includes transpose graph $G^T$.

But, I totally didn't understand why cannot use increasing order of original graph. Kosaraju's algorithm uses decreasing order of transpose graph.

Is there an any counter example about this? I'm really confusing.

Comment: 1. Something is wrong with your link.  2. Have you tried to construct a counterexample?  Try enumerating a bunch of graphs with 3 or 4 or 5 vertices.

Comment: I edited my link and I tried to find counterexample by drawing the graph, but I cannot find...

Comment: Check https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/47298/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/60503/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48625/755.  Do any of those help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have an exam 2 hours later, so I will check later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kosaraju's Algorithm-Strongly connected components](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48625/kosarajus-algorithm-strongly-connected-components), which contains the same answer below by K. Ali and whose accepted answer contains a counterexample.